# How to put a lights off effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

can anyone help me how to make a light off effect if i click any of my textboxes?

I found this idea in this site: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/stuff/lightsoff/

I want to do is when i click the textbox that particular textbox will be high-lighten and if i click that textbox again it will remove the light off effect.

Does anyone know how to do that?

html code:

```
 <input type="text" readonly id="myname1" style="width:1000px; height:30px !important " />
 <br />
 <br />
 <input type="text" readonly id="myname2" style="width:1000px; height:30px !important " />
```

script code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#myname1').on('click', function(){
        alert(1)      
    })    
})
$(function(){
    $('#myname2').on('click', function(){
        alert(2)      
    })    
})
</script>
```

Comment: inspect that page element and you will find out how it's built

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do that:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" readonly id="myname1" style="width:1000px; height:30px !important" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" readonly id="myname2" style="width:1000px; height:30px !important" />
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); /* Semi-transparent */
}

.highlight {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    var lightsOff = false;
    $('#myname1,#myname2').on('click', function () {
        lightsOff = !lightsOff;
        $('#overlay').fadeToggle(1000); /* Choose desired delay */
        if (!lightsOff)
            setTimeout((function() {
                $(this).removeClass('highlight');
            }).bind(this), 1000); /* Same delay */
        else
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
    })
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AP6kr/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic version I just made, take a look and mess around with it.

So we create an `overlay` this will take up the whole screen with a black background. We then want to have another `div` where the content we want to show will go, on this `div` we set `z-index: 1` so it sits on top of the overlay.

From here its just as simple as using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to get the effect we want.

**Note:** This is very basic version, you can do better then this so mess around and see what you can do with it. This should give you a good start.

### HTML:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="highlight">Test
    <br/><span class="on">On</span> | <span class="off">Off</span> 
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.overlay {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}
.highlight {
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

### jQuery:

```
$(".on").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
});

$(".off").click(function () {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/nhpRG/)